# Shell_NotifyIcon fails when called from a server in session 0 on Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-services

We have a large, old, application written using Visual Studio 6. We're having a problem with Shell_NotifyIcon failing on Windows 7 when it is called from one of our services in session 0. The service is trying to put up a tray icon.

Does anyone know what is causing this failure and how to work around the problem?

Comment: Google "session 0 isolation" to find out why this is no longer possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's because Session 0 Isolation feature added, a result of which is that services cannot directly interact with a users desktop.  To configure a service with the right to interact with the user, the [SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) modifier must be present it the services registry keys Type parameter. (Windows Internals 6)

Comment: Interactive processes allow services to display UI, but their UI is placed in a special session. They cannot communicate with user logon  sessions. The application was already broken even on Windows XP once you did Fast User Switching.

Answer (score -1):

As you probably noticed, there is no tray in Session 0! It is not surprising that Shell_NotifyIcon fails there.

The tray is provided by the Explorer.exe process. If you [start a copy of Explorer in Session 0](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/HowToShowTrayIconsInSession0.html) your calls should magically succeed, but please proceed with caution as user interfaces in Session 0 are discouraged.